# Density of C∞ -divergence free functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Here functions are defined on $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^{n}}$. My question is :

Are the $C^{\infty}$ -divergence free functions dense in $C_{0}^{\infty}$  or in some sobolev space ?

Thanks

Comment: What does divergence free mean?

Comment: Divergence free functions cannot be dense in function spaces containing non-divergence free functions (if you consider topologies that respect derivatives...)

Comment: it means  div u = 0

Comment: @daw: What is the divergence of a function (and not of a vector field)?